# Unable to enable zswap on digitalocean ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, linux-kernel

I'm trying to enable zswap on my digitalocean Ubuntu 16.04 droplet without any luck.
I tried to apend `zswap.enabled=1` to grub's `GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT` and to `GRUB_CMD_LINUX` and after that run `update-grub`.

I also trie to enable it in runtime by executing `echo 1 > /sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled` as suggested by ArchWiki but it tells me that `/sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled: No such file or directory`, folder parameters contains only max_pool_percent.

As I've read zswap was merged into 3.11 kernel and I have `3.13.0-57`.

Anyway `dmesg | grep zswap` shows nothing. Is there any way I can enable it in such configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after I upgrade my kernel to 4.4 problem gone. Zswap works now.